# reRender value determine

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, rendered, selectoption

[image]Please find below code where I am facing problem with the reRender value. It's not working as expected. When I change **Campaign** value, as **Product** changes accordingly, Userlist below (which is in a different form) also needs to change accordingly. When I pass the campaign value in URL and reload the page, it's working fine. But I need not to do reload the page and handle the situation with reRender. Can someone please help? Change required in the highlighted reRender value, I am not getting what it should be.
**Apex page**

```
  ....
   <apex:form id="frm1">    
     <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="/apex/SampleDashboard" target="_top" class="btn">Back to Allocation</a>

             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="page-header">
                         <h1>
                             <small>
                                 <apex:outputText value="View/Transfer Product Allocations" rendered="{!userType != 'Rep' && userType != 'ReadonlyAdmin'}"/>
                                 <apex:outputText value="View Product Allocations" rendered="{!userType == 'Rep' || userType == 'ReadonlyAdmin'}"/>
                             </small>
                         </h1>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
      <apex:outputPanel id="pivot">
          <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!allocList.size == 0}">
               <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="well well-lg">
                        <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Campaign
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"><center>
                          <!--    <apex:actionFunction name="AJAXRefresh" action="{!updProductList}" rerender="frm1,pivot" status="actStatusId"/>  -->

                                <apex:selectList value="{!selCampaign}"  size="1">  <!--  onchange="AJAXRefresh();"-->
                                <!-- onchange="document.location.reload(true);"  -->
                              <apex:selectOptions value="{!campaigns}"></apex:selectOptions>
                            **<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updProductList}" status="actStatusId"  reRender="pivot,theTabPanel,tabOne,hierPb,pb"/>**
                              </apex:selectList>  </center>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>                       


                      </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Product
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"><center>
                               <apex:selectList value="{!selectedProductlot}" size="1">
                                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!productList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                  **<apex:actionSupport action="{!refreshAvailableQuantities}" event="onchange" status="actStatusId" reRender="pivot,theTabPanel,tabOne,hierPb,pb"/>**
                              </apex:selectList> </center>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>                              
                        </div> 
                      </div>    
                      </div> 
                      </div>    
                      </div>                              
          </apex:outputPanel>    
      </apex:outputPanel>

      </div>      

<apex:actionFunction name="setActiveTab" rerender="">
     <apex:param id="selTab" assignTo="{!selTab}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="well well-lg">
        <apex:tabPanel tabClass="nav nav-tabs" contentClass="tab-content" switchType="client" value="{!selTab}" id="theTabPanel">
    <apex:tab label="View Allocation" name="View" id="tabOne">
    <div class="well well-lg">
    <apex:outputPanel id="hierPb">
    <ul id="treeDemo" class="ztree">
    </ul>    
    <script>
        var m = {
        <apex:repeat value="{!availableQtyMap}" var="Key">
            <apex:repeat value="{!availableQtyMap[Key]}" var="mvalue">
                "{!Key}" : {!mvalue},            
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>}
        for (var i in zNodes) {
            var key = zNodes[i].userId;
            if(key != "" && zNodes[i].name != null)
                zNodes[i].name = zNodes[i].name.split("(")[0] + "(" +  m[key] + ")" ;
         }      
        if(document.readyState == 'complete')
        {
            j$.fn.zTree.init(j$("#treeDemo"), setting, zNodes);
        }
    </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Transfer Allocation" rendered="{!userType != 'Rep' && userType != 'ReadonlyAdmin'}" name="Transfer" id="tabTwo">
    <div class="well well-lg">
        <apex:pageMessages rendered="{!errMsg}"></apex:pageMessages>
        <style>.homeTab .bPageBlock {
    border-top: 0px; solid #1797c0;
}
.bPageBlock .detailList tr td, .bPageBlock .detailList tr th {
    border-bottom: 0px; solid #1797c0;
}
</style>

        <apex:pageBlock id="pb" rendered="{!!errMsg}" >
<script>
    var orgRemainingQty = {!remainingQty};
    var remainingQty = {!remainingQty};
    function clearAllInputs()
    {
        j$(".inpTransQty").val(0).change(); 
        remainingQty = orgRemainingQty;
     //   document.getElementById('Remaining').innerHTML = remainingQty;  
    }


    function distributeSpecified(eachCount)
    {
        var fromUser = document.getElementById('pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id').value;
        if(fromUser == '') alert('Please Select from User');
        else
        {
            var prevEleId = "" + fromUser ;
            var prevEle = document.getElementById(prevEleId);
            var ele = j$(prevEle).prev();
            var totalUsers = j$(".inpTransQty:visible").not(ele).length;
            var maxCount = Math.floor(remainingQty/totalUsers);            
           if(eachCount > maxCount)
           {
               if(fromUser == '{!CurUser.Id}')
                   alert('You have insufficient allocations for distributing ' + eachCount + ' among ' + totalUsers + ' users.');
               else
                   alert('User has insufficient allocations for distributing ' + eachCount + ' among ' + totalUsers + ' users.');
           }
           else
           {  
            j$(".inpTransQty:visible").not(ele).val(function(i,c){ return parseInt(c)+parseInt(eachCount) }).change(); 
            remainingQty=remainingQty-(eachCount * totalUsers);
          //  document.getElementById('Remaining').innerHTML = remainingQty;    
           }
        }
    }    



    function distributeEqually()
    {
        var fromUser = document.getElementById('pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id').value;
        if(fromUser == '') alert('Please Select from User');
        else
        {
            var prevEleId = "" + fromUser ;
            var prevEle = document.getElementById(prevEleId);
            var ele = j$(prevEle).prev();
            var totalUsers = j$(".inpTransQty:visible").not(ele).length;
            var eachCount = Math.floor(orgRemainingQty/totalUsers);
           // alert ("totalUsers " +totalUsers + "eachCount" + eachCount + "orgRemainingQty" + orgRemainingQty);
           if(eachCount == 0)
           {
               if(fromUser == '{!CurUser.Id}')
                   alert('You have insufficient allocations for equal distribution.');
               else
                   alert('User has insufficient allocations for equal distribution.');
           }
           else
           {
            j$(".inpTransQty:hidden").not(ele).val(0).change();            
            j$(".inpTransQty:visible").not(ele).val(eachCount).change(); 
            remainingQty=orgRemainingQty-(eachCount * totalUsers);
          //  document.getElementById('Remaining').innerHTML = remainingQty;    
           }
        }
    }    

    function refreshRemainingQty()
    {
        var alreadyAllocatedQty= 0;
        j$('.inpTransQty').each(function(){
            alreadyAllocatedQty+= parseFloat(this.value);  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
        });
        remainingQty = orgRemainingQty - alreadyAllocatedQty;
    }
</script>        
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Preview Allocations" rendered="{!allocList.size == 0}" onclick="if(document.getElementById('pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id').value == ''){ alert('Please select from user'); return false;}" action="{!previewAllocation}" status="actStatusId" rerender="pivot,pb"/>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!allocList.size == 0}"><input id="clearAll" class="btn" type="button" value="Clear All"  onclick="clearAllInputs(); return false;"/>  
                <input class="btn" id="disEqually" type="button" value="Distribute Equally"  onclick="distributeEqually(); return false;"/></apex:outputPanel>                                
                <apex:commandButton value="Confirm" rendered="{!allocList.size > 0}" action="{!addAllocation}" status="actStatusId"  rerender="pivot,hierPb,pb"/>                
                <apex:commandButton value="Back" rendered="{!allocList.size > 0}" action="{!Back}" status="actStatusId" rerender="pivot,hierPb,pb"/>                             
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <script>

  j$(function() {
    var selInd = true;
    var users = [ <apex:repeat value="{!userList}" var="usrLst"> 
                                  <apex:repeat value="{!usrLst}" var="usr">  
                                      <apex:outputText rendered="{!availableQtyMap[usr.userId] != 0}"> 
                                       {
                                            value: "{!usr.userId}",
                                            label: "{!usr.usrName} ({!availableQtyMap[usr.userId]})",
                                            desc: "{!usr.terrName}",
                                            availableQuantity: "{!availableQtyMap[usr.userId]}"
                                          },         
                                      </apex:outputText>             
                                   </apex:repeat>
                              </apex:repeat>
                              ];  

    j$( "#fromuser" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: users,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        selInd = true;
      //  alert('selInd' + selInd);
        j$( "#fromuser" ).val( ui.item.label );
        this.value = ui.item.label;      
        remainingQty =  ui.item.availableQuantity;
        orgRemainingQty = ui.item.availableQuantity; 
        document.getElementById("pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id").value = ui.item.value;        
        document.getElementById("pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem1:fromuser-nameHid").value = ui.item.label;        
        j$( "#fromuser-description" ).html( 'Terr:' + ui.item.desc );
        changedFlag = false;
        clearAllInputs();
        return false;
      },
      response: function(event, ui) {  
            selInd = false;   
           // alert('selInd' + selInd);  
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                var str = this.value;                
                document.getElementById("pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id").value = '';
                j$( "#fromuser" ).val('');
                j$( "#fromuser-description" ).html( 'User selected does not have allocations available.' );
            } else {
            }
        },
        change: function(event,ui){
       // alert('selInd' + selInd);

            if(!selInd) //this.value != j$( "#fromuser" ).attr('value'))
            {
                document.getElementById("pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id").value = '';
                j$( "#fromuser-description" ).html( 'Please select from User from Options available.' );
                remainingQty =  0;
                orgRemainingQty = 0; 
                clearAllInputs();
            }
        }

    })

    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return j$( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

  });

  function enableDisableButtons(ele)
  {
      if(ele.value == '')
      {
          document.getElementById("disEqually").disabled = false;
         // document.getElementById("clearAll").disabled = false;
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById("disEqually").disabled = true;
        //  document.getElementById("clearAll").disabled = true;
      }      
  }

  </script>
 <apex:pageMessages />


        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!allocList.size > 0}">
        <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Preview Transfer
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs1" columns="1">
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                <apex:outputLabel ></apex:outputLabel>                
                                <apex:outputText >From User: {!fromUserName}</apex:outputText>   
                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            <!--div class="table-responsive" style="background-color: whitesmoke; height: 300px;"-->
                             <apex:dataTable styleClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" rendered="{!allocList.size > 0}" value="{!allocList}" var="alloc" id="pbt">            
                                <apex:column headerValue="To User" value="{!alloc.toUserName}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" value="{!alloc.Quantity}"/>                        
                            </apex:dataTable>
                            <!--/div--> 
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                             </div> 
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                Please review and click on Confirm to initiate Allocation Transfer.
                            </div>                      
                        </div>                       


                      </div>
                      </div>  
      </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" columns="2" rendered="{!allocList.size == 0}">     
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsItem1">
                <apex:outputLabel >From User </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputPanel >                                        
                    <input id="fromuser" value="{!fromUserName}" disabled="true" size="40"/>     
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!fromUserName}" id="fromuser-nameHid"/>                
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ></apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsItem2" >
                <apex:inputHidden value="{!fromUser}" id="fromuser-id"/> 

                   <pre style="font-family:sans-serif; border: 0px; " id="fromuser-description">{!userTerrDesc}</pre>
                    <!--apex:outputLabel >To User </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel >                                        
                        <input id="touser"/>
                        <apex:inputHidden value="{!toUser}" id="touser-id"/> 
                        <p id="touser-description"></p>              
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    -->
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>          


            <!--apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsItem3">
                <apex:outputLabel style="color:Red">Effective Remaining Qty<br/>(After Transfer)</apex:outputLabel>
                <p style="color:Red" id = "Remaining"></p>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            -->

</apex:pageBlockSection>
<script>
    if(document.readyState == 'complete')
    {
       j$('#fromuser').prop("disabled",false);
       j$('#input-filter').prop("disabled",false);   
       j$('#toUserSearch').filterTable({
            inputSelector: '#input-filter'
        });
    }
   // document.getElementById('Remaining').innerHTML = remainingQty;    
</script>  
<apex:inputHidden value="{!qty}" id="allocqty" />
<apex:inputHidden value="{!toUser}" id="touser-id"/> 
<apex:outputPanel id="toUsersSec" rendered="{!allocList.size == 0}">
    <div style="background-color: whitesmoke;" >
    <script>
    var prevValue;

    function inputOffFocus(ele,usrId)
    {

        var fromUser = document.getElementById('pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id').value;
        if(fromUser == '' && parseFloat(ele.value) > 0)
        {
            alert('Please select from User');
            j$(ele).val(prevValue).change();
            ele.nextSibling.innerHTML = '';
        }
        else if(usrId == fromUser && parseFloat(ele.value) > 0)
        {
            alert('Products cannot be transferred between the same users. Please update the To and Search fields for valid product allocations and transfers.');
            j$(ele).val(prevValue).change();
            ele.nextSibling.innerHTML = '';
        }
        else
        {
            if(ele.value == '') ele.value = 0;
            var checkRemaining = parseFloat(remainingQty) + parseFloat(prevValue) - parseFloat(ele.value);
            if(parseFloat(checkRemaining) < 0)
            {
                alert('You do not have sufficient allocations to complete this request.');
                j$(ele).val(prevValue).change();
                ele.focus();
            }
            else
            {
                remainingQty = parseInt(checkRemaining) ;
            //    document.getElementById('Remaining').innerHTML = remainingQty;
                ele.nextSibling.innerHTML = '';
            }        
        }
    }

    </script>
    <!-- Commenting this lines to implement sorting facility 
    <table class="table" style="width:98%;margin-bottom:0;">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headerRow">
                    <th class="col-md-3 headerRow" scope="col">User Name</th>
                    <th class="col-md-6 headerRow" scope="col">Territory</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1 headerRow" scope="col">Available</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2 headerRow" scope="col">Quantity</th>              
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </table> -->
    </div>
    <div style="height:350px; background-color: whitesmoke;"  class = "table-responsive" >
         <table style ="width: 1020px;">
            <thead style="display: block;">
                <tr class="headerRow">
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-3" scope="col"><apex:outputLabel >Search Table:</apex:outputLabel>
            <input id="input-filter" disabled="true"/> <!-- onkeyup="enableDisableButtons(this);" oninput="enableDisableButtons(this);"/--></th>
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-6" scope="col"></th>
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-1" scope="col"></th>
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-2" scope="col">
                    <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
                        onblur="document.getElementById('massAddEle').innerHTML = '';" onfocus="var frm1UserEle = j$('#' + document.getElementById('pg:frm1:pb:pbs:pbsItem2:fromuser-id').value).prev(); var totUsers = j$('.inpTransQty:visible').not(frm1UserEle).length;   var maxPossible = Math.floor(remainingQty/totUsers); document.getElementById('massAddEle').innerHTML = 'Remaining Qty: ' + remainingQty + '.<br/>Max Limit: ' + maxPossible ;"/>
                    <input class="btn" id="disSpecified" type="button" value="Add" onclick="distributeSpecified(j$(this).prev().val()); j$(this).prev().focus();"/>
                    <p id="massAddEle"></p></th>              
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>    
        <!-- table id="toUserSearch" class="table table-hover table-striped">    -->
        <table style ="width: 1120px;" id="toUserSearch" class="table tablesorter table-sm table-hover table-striped filterTable">
            <thead style="display: block;">
                <tr class="headerRow">
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-3 headerRow" scope="col">User Name</th>
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-6 headerRow" scope="col">Territory</th>
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-1 headerRow" scope="col">Available</th>
                    <th style ="width: 250px;" class="col-md-2 headerRow" scope="col">Quantity</th>              
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="display: block; overflow: auto; height: 230px;">
                <apex:repeat value="{!userList}" var="usrLst"> 
                  <apex:repeat value="{!usrLst}" var="usr">   
                      <tr class="visible">
                      <td style ="width: 255px;" class="col-md-3" >{!usr.usrName}</td>
                      <td style ="width: 255px;" class="col-md-6">{!usr.terrName}</td>
                      <td style ="width: 255px;" class="col-md-1" >{!availableQtyMap[usr.userId]}</td>
                      <td style ="width: 255px;" class="col-md-2" ><apex:inputText styleClass="inpTransQty" style="background-color:{!IF(usr.allocCount == 0,'white','yellow')}" 
                      value="{!usr.allocCount}" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' 
                      onchange="if(this.value != 0) this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; else this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';"
                      onfocus="prevValue =  parseFloat(this.value); this.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'Remaining Balance: ' + remainingQty;if(this.value==0) this.value='';"
                      onblur="inputOffFocus(this,'{!usr.userId}');"/><p Id="{!usr.UserId}"  style="color:Red"></p>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                   </apex:repeat>
              </apex:repeat>            
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- To sort table -->
    <script>                
            if(document.readyState == 'complete')
            {                
                var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();                
                j$('.tablesorter').tablesorter();  
            }    
            else
            {
                var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
                j$(document).ready(function(){  
                    j$('.tablesorter').tablesorter();                                
                }); 
            }
    </script>        

        <script> refreshRemainingQty(); </script>
     </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </div>
                      </div>   
                      </div>    
                      </div>   
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the issue is you are using two form tag on the page .

The action function Rerender does not work well with two forms on the page ,hence the solution would be to use only one form tag on the page

Comment: I have put it in one form and updated the code accordingly. Still it's not working.

Comment: Can you please let me know my syntax. I have updated accordingly, still facing the issue